# Using lapply to cycle through rows of a data frame and name objects from stored values in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows:

```
dat <- data.frame(ALIAS = c("Bill_Query", "Bob_Query", "Bernardo_Query", 
                               "Becky_Query", "Betsy_Query", "Xander_Query"),
                     FOOD = c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", 
                              "Kiwi", "Pear", "Steak Tartare"))
```

I need to loop through the data frame and create a list which stores each person's individual query:

```
queries <- lapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x) {
  dat[x, 2] <- paste("SELECT * FROM", dat[x,1])
})
```

I am trying to name each list item based on column 1 of the data frame, but cannot figure out how to do so. Basically, I would like to be able to type in,

```
queries[["Bill_Query"]
```

And get back:

```
"SELECT * FROM Apples"
```

Can someone help me out and show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try naming your list:

```r
names(queries) <- dat[,1]
```

This gives you

```r
> queries[["Bill_Query"]]
[1] "SELECT * FROM Bill_Query"
```

Comment: One more hint: `dat[x, 2] <-` inside your function doesn't make any sense, I guess. I suggest removing this.